# Hygienic fitness of frozen fully cooked food

Tags: storage-lifetime, food-preservation

I cooked chicken soup and freeze it.For how long I can eat it

Comment: Should we assume that you're going to reheat it before you try to eat it?

Comment: Food that stays completely frozen will stay safe indefinitely. It won't stay tasty forever, but soup will continue to taste good for months when it's reheated.

Comment: Frozen at -18°C, that is...

Answer (score 0):

Freezing is a great way to preserve food for many months, but not for any longer than 1  year to prevent freezer burn or moisture and flavor loss.  It is a good idea to prevent bacteria growth by only reheating food once, so avoid keeping any leftover reheated soup by refreezing or refrigerating.  Freezing in small batches, and reheating for that meal can minimize waste.